# Microsoft VS Code and Angular 2 tags in HTML linter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I just started using Angular 2 in VSCode.  Using the Angular.io "Tour of Heroes" as an example, the built-in HTML linter does not recognize the Angular 2 directives in the HTML tags, such as `*ng-if` or `(click)`, as you can see in this screen shot:

[image]

Is there some setting or extension I am missing?  This is valid HTML code in an Angular 2 app and I don't want a lot of errors for nothing -- but I want to use the linter in case I make actual errors elsewhere.

Comment: The errors are apparently coming from an HTMLHint plugin I had.  I removed it, and the errors are gone.  I'll have to find it there's an HTML linter for Code that understands the Angular 2 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add exceptions to the list of attributes in the HTMLHint extension:

```
"htmlhint.options": {
    "attr-lowercase": ["*ngIf", "*ngFor"]
}
```

The attr-lowercase rule can be true, false or an array of attribute names to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this fragment into you settings file (.vscode\settings.json in workspace or edit via File>Preferences>Settings):

```
"htmlhint.options": {
    "tagname-lowercase": true,
    "attr-value-double-quotes": true,
    "attr-no-duplication": true,
    "tag-pair": true,
    "spec-char-escape": true,
    "id-unique": true,
    "src-not-empty": true,
    "title-require": true
}
```

With this, HTMLHint plugin will parse correctly Angular templates and stop throw warnings.

Comment: I already had these, and none of these helped with the issue.  See the accepted answer.