# Disabling the squiggly green line in Angular 2+ html template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular2-template, angular2-forms

How can I get rid of the following squiggly green line while I am editing the html template of an Angular 2+ >= v2 (v2 or higher) project without changing the template itself:
Lets say I have the following line:

```
         <textarea [(ngModel)]="jobDescription"  cols="40" rows="5" (ngModelChange)="textAreaEmpty()"></textarea>
         <br/>
```

Above line inside Visual Studio Code (1.11.1) Editor looks like the following

[image]

Notice the green squiggly line? If I hover over it I see the following hint:

[image]

Suggesting : "*The attribute name of* [[(ngModel)]] *must be in lowercase*. I want to ignore this suggestion. How can I achieve this without turning off the entire editor suggestions?

*I am happy with other potential editor suggestions but for this particular one I would like to turn this green alert off.*

**Update 1:**
my workspace settings looks like the following now

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/*.js.map": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "html.suggest.angular1": false
}
```

**Update 2**: Even adding *"html.suggest.angular1": false* did not disable these warning and I still see them in my editor:

Note: I have the following Extensions installed:

- Angular TypeScript Snippets for VS Code
- angular2-inline
- Azure Functions Tools - Extensions for VS Code
- VS Code - Debugger for Chrome
- VS Code ESLint extension
- Git History (including git log)
- Visual Studio Code HTML Snippets
- vscode-htmlhint
- IntelliSense for CSS class names
- Latest TypeScript and Javascript Grammer
- Visual Studio Team Services Extension
- Visual Studio Team Services Status Extension for Visual Studio Code

[image]

**Final Update:**

In my case the **HTMLHint** was the culprit. I disabled the extension and reloaded the work space and now I do not see any more squiggly green line.

Comment: Just a note, `AngularJS` refers to `Angular 1.x`, wheres now, `Angular` refers to `Angular 2+`. Your post talks about `Angular2/4`, so `AngularJS` isn't right for it

Comment: I edited the title and post to reflect the version of the Angular. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @MHOOS Are you using any extensions on your vscode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings

Open up the html pane and check this line:

```
// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests Angular V1 tags and properties.
  "html.suggest.angular1": true,
```

it should be `false`.

Comment: an up-vote for the response because I was not even aware of the existence of such setting but this did not fix my problem and I still see the squiggly green line. For you information I just updated my question with an update showing my workspace settings.

Comment: @MHOOS thanks for the feedback I'll search for another answer :-)

Comment: I added the list of extensions installed in my visual Studio to the question. Just to confirm: The problem has not been resolved yet even if I set "html.suggest.angular1" to false.

Comment: @MHOOS it is probably an error from vscode-htmlhint. Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945780/microsoft-vs-code-and-angular-2-tags-in-html-linter

Comment: You were right. I disabled the extension and squiggly green lines disappeared. Well done!

Comment: @MHOOS Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is coming from TSLint/Codelyzer, which is specific to the project itself. Unfortunately, while TSLint supports rule flags in code to disable rules for specific lines, there is no support for this in HTML files. you could edit out this rule in the tsconfig.json, but a more elegant solution might be to go to File > Settings > Preferences, select the TSLint section, and add the glob `*.html` to `"tslint.exclude".

EDIT: Undeleted per @echonax 's request, but I deleted it in the first place because I think his answer is the correct one! I'll leave it here regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get rid of the annotations by adding a .htmlhintrc file to the root path in my project and adding the following values:

{
    "attr-lowercase": false,
    "doctype-first": false
}